# django widget fields readonly in html

Tags: django, widget

Im trying to use fields that can be only read in a html template like this using widget include

```
{% include "bases/fields.html" with field=form_sales.idsale %}
```

does not show me readonly property if i use

```
|is_readonly=true
```

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, establish this line at the beginnig of the template :

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
```

Then, use it like this :

```
{% include "bases/fields.html" with field=form_sales.idsale|attr:"readonly:True" %}
```

That should do it